# React native project with expo-localization and i18n-js

Tags: react-native, localization, expo, i18n-js

i am currently trying to implement localization depending on the system language of the device but something is not working as required.

I followed the exact same code on expo documentation, for eg. for the button i have i keep getting `[MISSING "EN-GB.LOGIN" TRANSLATION]` instead of `LOGIN`.

Here is my code:

welcomeScreen.js

```
import * as Localization from 'expo-localization';
import i18n from 'i18n-js';

i18n.translations = {
en: { login: 'LOGIN'},
ar: { login: 'تسجيل الدخول'},
};

i18n.locale = Localization.locale;
i18n.fallbacks = true;

function WelcomeScreen() {
return (

<Button
      title={i18n.t('login')}
    />
)}
```

So instead of the code above i decided to go with this:

i18n.js

```
import i18n from 'i18n-js';
import * as Localization from 'expo-localization';
import ar from './locales/ar';  
import en from './locales/en';

i18n.translations = {  
'en': en,
'ar': ar,
};

i18n.locale = Localization.locale.search(/-|_/) !== -1? 
Localization.locale.slice(0, 2): Localization.locale;

i18n.fallbacks = true;

export default i18n;
```

en.js

```
const en = { 
'SignUp':{
SignUp:"Sign Up"
}}
```

ar.js

```
const ar = {
'SignUp':{
SignUp:"الاشتراك"
}}
```

SignUpScreen.js

```
import I18n from '../config/i18n';

function RegisterScreen(props) {
return(
<Button title={I18n.t('SignUp.SignUp')}
)}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you try to `console.log(Localization.locale)` ... it's not gonna be just `en` (the key in `i18n.translations` expected by `i18n`) ... it'd in the form of `en_countryCode` ... so you have to slice that part

```
  i18n.locale = Localization.locale.search(/-|_/) !== -1
    ? Localization.locale.slice(0, 2)
    : Localization.locale;
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for getting back to me, will give this a try. Do you suggest i use `import i18n from 'i18n-js'` like the code above or this library `import I18n from 'ex-react-native-i18n'`?

Comment: I personally use `i18next`

Comment: is there a difference between them?

Comment: if i decide to use i18next do i need make alot of changes to my code?

Comment: I work in ejected-projects ... which is kinda different than expo-projects (I mean ejected-projects give u more flexibility over what modules to choose) ... I'd say go with the one that 'd work smoothly with expo..

Comment: thats completely true, btw i gave your code a test and instead of `indexOf('_')` it should be `indexOf('-')` why is that?

Comment: Yes correct ... according to the err-message `[MISSING "EN-GB.LOGIN" TRANSLATION]` .. but you have to check for both `_` and `-` ... cause they vary based on android-version

Comment: can i do something like this `Localization.locale.indexOf('-' || "_") !== -1? Localization.locale.slice(0, 2): Localization.locale`

Comment: Hey, my friend, I could keep getting back to you ... and this could lead to getting more and more correct-answers ... but believe me, google has to be your best friend if you wanna be a good developer :)

Comment: Trust me i got told that before 100 times, and i have been searching google for days now trying to solve this problem and couldnt get anywhere. da e7na masreyen zay ba3d ya3ni

Comment: Lol ... keep asking then

Comment: Hi sorry to bother you again, i updated my question above with the code i am currently using, can you please tell me if what i am doing is correct. Would really appreciate it.

Comment: yes, correct ... Does the error go away? ... <feel free to ask, you're welcome...>